# Dropdown from navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried to follow [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown_navbar.asp), but I can't seem to find out why the dropdown menu won't show up at all when hovering over the dropdown button in the nav bar.

This is the HTML part of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-container">

  <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
        <a href="newsale.php" class="new_sale">New</a>
        <a href="sales.php">Sales</a>
        <a href="account.php">Account</a>
        
        <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
    
<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS part of the code:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
 
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

#main-container {
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#navbar a.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.new_sale {
    background-color: green;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap you shouldn't be pounding your own CSS onto it. Also, please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are hiding the content which goes over the boundaries of your navbar and dropdown.

You need to remove

```
overflow: hidden;
```

from your `#navbar` and `.dropdown` class, check this [fiddle](https://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/dypBeLy)

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot about the that one. But after removing the `overflow` - Why does the navbar buttons gets bigger then the navbar if I use background-color on it? How can I avoid that?

Comment: You can see here: https://ibb.co/PD0yHmD . Green one has always background color, and red one is when I hover.

Comment: This happens because the buttons are higher than the navbar. Just set the navbar height to 54px and it should work (I updated my fiddle, you can check it again). Alternatively, reduce the vertical padding of your `.navbar a` class to match the height of the navbar.